# How to start bitnami rubystack environment on Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, bitnami

On windows, I use file user Bitnami Rubystack to start the environment.

How can I start it on Linux Ubuntu?

Comment: Please Explain you question in brief,
means what are you requirement e.g are you want to setup rails in Environment in Linux

Comment: I have installed bitnami rubystack on Linux Ubuntu. Using windows I run the file user_bitnumi_rubystack to start the ruby environment where I can enter commands like "rails s" for server. Now do I start the environment in Linux terminal?

Comment: You have to open your terminal-->go to project-->run(rails s)-->before that must ensure that you have created your database and run bundle and db:migrate commands

Comment: that one tries to download and install rails again, but want to run the already installed rubystack rails.

Answer (score 1):

This is for anyone that finds there way to this question in the future.

You need to go to the /home/bitnami/stack folder.

```
bitnami@ubuntu:~$ cd /home/bitnami/stack
```

Now run sudo ./rubyconsole

```
bitnami@ubuntu:~/stack$ sudo ./rubyconsole
```

You will be asked for the bitnami user password. Enter bitnami.

```
[sudo] password for bitnami: bitnami
```

Now the prompt will change to indicate you are in the bitnami ruby console. See below.

Now go to the projects folder.

```
root@ubuntu:/opt/bitnami# cd projects
root@ubuntu:/opt/bitnami/projects#
```

Now you can create your rails project.

Answer (score 0):

**To autorun at startup for Ubuntu Precise:**

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/init.d/
ln -s /opt/rubystack-1.9.3-24/ctlscript.sh bitnami-rubystack
chmod +x bitnami-rubystack
update-rc.d bitnami-rubystack defaults
update-rc.d bitnami-rubystack enable
```

To remove:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f bitnami-rubystack remove
```

I began with the instructions from the Bitnami wiki, but they didn't seem to work out of the box: http://wiki.bitnami.com/Native_Installers_Quick_Start_Guide#How_to_start_automatically_the_Stack_on_Linux.3f

**If you want to start manually:**

```
sudo -i
cd /opt/rubystack-1.9.3-24
chmod +x manager-linux-x64.run
./manager-linux-x64.run
```